# Python future date in filename

Tags: python, date, datetime

hi i am trying to save a file rename with an added date (ex. 01_02 to 01_03), if possible.

this is the code im testing:
can this be accomplished to add tomorrows date to a renamed file?

```
 import os
 from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
        
 dt = datetime.today()
 td = timedelta(days=1)
 Current_Date = dt + td
        
 Current_Date = dt.strftime ("%m %d %Y")
 os.rename(r'01_02_originalname', r'01_02_rename' + str(Current_Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_` as delimiter between date and filename
Then split the name to find the original name and prepend the date you want

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  
dt = datetime.today()
td = timedelta(days=1)
Current_Date = dt + td
Current_Date = dt.strftime ("%m_%d_%Y_")
current_name = '04_24_2022_original_name'
original_name = current_name.split('_',3)[-1]
os.rename(current_name, str(Current_Date)+original_name)
```